# How to identify if a GAC assembly is loading

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, gac, .net-assembly

I have installed Visual Studio 2011 beta, and have found that a website I was working on has since stopped working. It has been suggested that there is an `MVC` or `Razor` assembly from the GAC which is loading and taking over. How would I check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the application in Debug mode and watch the `Output window` in Visual Studio. It will list every assembly as it is loaded, you will recognize GAC assemblies easily by its full file path.

Answer (score 3):

Just of interest let's do it i runtime. The idea is - check out [Assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.globalassemblycache.aspx) property of all loaded MVC assemblies.

Put the following code snippet somewhere in `Page_Load()` and see in a file whether specific assembly was loaded from GAC:

```
using System.Linq;
var items = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                     .GetAssemblies()
                     .Where(a => a.FullName.Contains("MVC"))
                     .Select(a => String.Format(
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                         "[{0}] {1}",
                                         a.GlobalAssemblyCache,
                                         a.FullName));

File.WriteAllLines("c:\\assembliesdump.txt", items .ToArray());
```

Output will be like shown below (log4net filter as example):

> [False] log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821