# Through reflection, determine if a referenced assembly was loaded from the GAC

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I am trying to find a way to determine which assemblies were installed in the GAC and which were referenced directly, and therefore, were most likely copied local, in an assembly's referenced assemblies (the results returned from Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()). My only starting point is from GetReferencedAssemblies().

In other words if myAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies() returns System.Windows.Forms and MyNamespace.MyOtherAssembly, System.Windows.Forms was probably referenced from the GAC and MyNamespace.MyOtherAssembly was probably referenced directly from the dll and copied local. But how do I determine that?

P.S. The code may not be running on the machine that the assembly was originally created on so a referenced assembly in the GAC now may not have been there when the original assembly was compiled on a different machine.

Comment: The linked answer still does not answer this question as I am not reflecting on assemblies running on or local to my machine.

Comment: I don't think this information is available. Can you tell us more about what you are trying to do more generally? There may be other ways to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I will definitely try. From a given path (most likely a network path), I need to get a list of assembly dlls and a list of dependencies. If at all possible, I need to only get dependencies that were not loaded in the GAC but were copied local to the original dll, and therefore, should be in the same physical location  as the original dll (or in a subfolder). I might just scan the directory again and try to match up FullName.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of the question, [How to identify if a GAC assembly is loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571658/how-to-identify-if-a-gac-assembly-is-loading). It provides [the answer you seek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9571700/467473). The `bool` property [`Assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.globalassemblycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) indicates whether or not the assembly was loaded from GAC:

```
using System.Linq;
string[] assemblies = AppDomain
                     .CurrentDomain
                     .GetAssemblies()
                     .Where(a => a.FullName.Contains("MVC"))
                     .Select(a => String.Format(
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        "[{0}] {1}",
                        a.GlobalAssemblyCache,
                        a.FullName
                        ))
                     .ToArray()
                     ;

File.WriteAllLines("c:\\assembliesdump.txt", items .ToArray());
```

Comment: Your answer seems to indicate that you are looking at assemblies loaded from the current app domain. I'm loading an assembly from a UNC path that was not created (or referenced) by the project. So, just to try to be clear, will Assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache tell me if the referenced assembly in question was referenced from the GAC? Remember, the assemblies I am looking at are not local in any way to the machine the code is running on.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. It tells you whether the assembly is loaded from the GAC at run time, not whether it was in the GAC at compile time.

Comment: Having to choose between a time machine and telepathy, some pragmatism in the request seems appropriate.  Nothing is certain until the assembly actually gets loaded into a process.

Comment: @mikez: how do you propose, determining *after the fact* and on a *different machine*, the state of the machine on which the code was compiled? One could I suppose, create a custom build step to determine that information and and bind it to the executable as a resource, but it's pointless information.

Comment: Well, usually, dlls that are referenced from somewhere other than the GAC have there Copy Local property set to true. I wasn't sure if this was stored in the main assembly's metadata or not.

Comment: That was supposed to read, DON'T have there Copy Local set to true.

Comment: @BrandenBoucher, you might want to read up on how the CLR locates and binds assemblies: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd727509.aspx. The value of `CopyLocal` is up to the developer: it's *default* value is `true` but that can be changed at any time. You should also note that if a matching assembly has already been loaded into the app domain, that is the version used to satisfy the request, regardless of whether the actual assembly is GAC'd, in the bin directory or located elsewhere.

Comment: @NicholasCarey, I appreciate that. It's very good information to know. But that really isn't what my question is about. I wasn't asking how my program loads assemblies, I was asking if it was possible to determine if the original developer set CopyLocal to true or false. This becomes important if you wish to create a list of dependency files to copy with an assembly but want to avoid assemblies that were in the GAC.